# How to put status emoji into embed thumbnail when user status

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried doing `.setThumbnail(member.presence.activities[0]?.emoji?.url)`
but it never worked.

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: "status",
        category: "fun",
        aliases: [""],
        description: "Shows status of users",
        usage: "status <@user>",
    },
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {

        let user = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.find(r => r.user.username.toLowerCase() === args.join(' ').toLocaleLowerCase()) || message.guild.members.cache.find(ro => ro.displayName.toLowerCase() === args.join(' ').toLocaleLowerCase()) || message.member;

        if (!user.presence.activities.length) {
            const sembed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(user.user.username, user.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                .setColor("GREEN")
                .setThumbnail(user.user.displayAvatarURL())
                .addField("**No Status**", 'This user does not have any custom status!')
                .setFooter(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL())
                .setTimestamp()
            message.channel.send(sembed)
            return undefined;
        }

        user.presence.activities.forEach((activity) => {

            if (activity.type === 'CUSTOM_STATUS') {
                const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setAuthor(user.user.username, user.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                    .setColor("GREEN")
                    .addField("**Status**", `**Custom status** -\n${activity.emoji || "No Emoji"} | ${activity.state}`)
                    .setThumbnail(user.user.displayAvatarURL())
                    .setFooter(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL())
                    .setTimestamp()
                message.channel.send(embed)
            }
            else if (activity.type === 'PLAYING') {
                let name1 = activity.name
                let details1 = activity.details
                let state1 = activity.state
                let image = user.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })

                const sembed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setAuthor(`${user.user.username}'s Activity`)
                    .setColor(0xFFFF00)
                    .setThumbnail(image)
                    .addField("**Type**", "Playing")
                    .addField("**App**", `${name1}`)
                    .addField("**Details**", `${details1 || "No Details"}`)
                    .addField("**Working on**", `${state1 || "No Details"}`)
                message.channel.send(sembed);
            }
            else if (activity.type === 'LISTENING' && activity.name === 'Spotify' && activity.assets !== null) {

                let trackIMG = `https://i.scdn.co/image/${activity.assets.largeImage.slice(8)}`;
                let trackURL = `https://open.spotify.com/track/${activity.syncID}`;

                let trackName = activity.details;
                let trackAuthor = activity.state;
                let trackAlbum = activity.assets.largeText;

                trackAuthor = trackAuthor.replace(/;/g, ",")

                const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setAuthor('Spotify Track Info', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/408668371039682560.png')
                    .setColor("GREEN")
                    .setThumbnail(trackIMG)
                    .addField('Song Name', trackName, true)
                    .addField('Album', trackAlbum, true)
                    .addField('Author', trackAuthor, false)
                    .addField('Listen to Track', `${trackURL}`, false)
                    .setFooter(user.displayName, user.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                message.channel.send(embed);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Doas `member.presence.activities[0]?.emoji?.url` returns the url?

Comment: I think replacing `member.presence.activities[0]?.emoji?.url` with `member.presence.activities[0].emoji.url` will work because I never see using ? on activities

Comment: hey so i tried it but i got this error.
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: member is not defined

Comment: btw i had it working on a dif bot long time ago but i lost all the files and i dont rmb what it was so yeah btw that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I don't have idea about getting emojis in an activity
but try this

```js
member.presence.activities[0]?.emoji?.url()
```

but i'm sure this will work

```js
  let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1]) || message.guild.member(message.author)
if (!member.presence.activities || member.presence.activities.length == 0) {
    embed.addField('⚽️ Activity:', 'Not playing anything')
} else {
    const activity = member.presence.activities[0];
    embed.addField('⚽️ Activity:', `${activity.type} ${activity.name}\n${activity.details}\n${activity.state}`);
}
```

Comment: i dont think you understand what im trying to do. i already know how to make that but what im trying to do is make the emoji in my status look as a thumbnail in the embed.

Comment: you mean in any image format?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah hello so, i fixed it but there is always a problem.
for members that has emoji in status the command works and returns the embed with what i want.
for members that dosent have the emoji the command shows none.
here is my codes

```
c

onst Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "status",
  aliases: ["status"],
  execute: async(client, message, args, data, db) => {
    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    const userFlags = (await message.member.user.fetchFlags()).toArray();
    const activities = [];
          let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1]) || message.guild.member(message.author)
if (!member.presence.activities || member.presence.activities.length == 0) {
    const embed1 = new Discord.messageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`No status.`)
    .setColor(`#800080`)
    message.channel.send(embed1)
} else {
    const activity = member.presence.activities[0];
        const about = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(`#800080`)
    .setThumbnail(member.presence.activities[0].emoji.url)
    .setTitle(`${activity.state}`)   
        message.channel.send(about)
  if (member.presence.activities[0].emoji.url == 0){
    const about2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(`#800080`)
    .setTitle(`${activity.state}`)
            message.channel.send(about2)
  }
}
    }
}
module.exports.help = {
    name: "status",
    description: "Gets user's status from a mention",
    usage: "status <mention>",
    type: "Utility",
}
```